# Select build configuration DbContext migration

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I can update the database in my web config:

```
Update-Database -Verbose
```

When the database is deployed, I have a different connection string defined in the web.config.debug transform file.

How can I use the correct connection string for the build configuration?

For example:

`Web.config`:

```xml
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyConnection" 
             connectionString="My_Local_Connection_String"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

`Web.config.Debug`:

```xml
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyConnection" 
             connectionString="My_Debug_Connection_String" 
             xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" 
             xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

`Web.config.Release`:

```xml
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyConnection" 
             connectionString="My_Release_Connection_String" 
             xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"
             xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Once I've proved that the migration locally is fine, I need to make the same migration on the connection string the `Web.config.Debug` and, assuming that works then the release version.

How to I tell EF which configuration transform to use?

Comment: Do you mean your web.config has your test database connection string and you want your published project to replace it with your production connection string. Because FYI the transforms are only applied on publish, not on build.

Comment: Would you describe your question more precisely? What do you mean by correct connection string for build configuration?

Comment: @ThomasBoby Aye, I know they are performed on publish.  So, is it a case of copying the connection string out of the config file or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably fancier solutions, but a simple one that comes to mind is:

1. Put all your connection strings in the web.config with appropriate names (ie. MyApplication-Debug, MyApplication-Release)
2. In the migrations configuration class, specify the connection string using a preprocessor #if, like

   ```
   internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyApplicationContext>
   {
      public Configuration()
      {
         AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;

         string connectionStringName;
   #if DEBUG
         connectionStringName = "MyApplication-Debug";
   #else
         connectionStringName = "MyApplication-Release";
   #endif

         TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(connectionStringName);
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Whilst that would work, it would be horrible.  Fellow developers would walk past me with disgust.

Comment: Why? This does what you want to do. If it's wrong, maybe you have to change your requirements. For the record, I would never apply migrations to a release db.

Comment: Because now I have a config that needs to be aware of all the build configurations.  My connection names aren't common through environments.  Every time I have a build configuration I add another pre-compile if.  You're right in that it is functionally do-able, but it's not a *good* solution.

Comment: You only mentioned debug and release in the question. But in any case, you will need a connection string per environment/build configuration, you will need to store it somewhere and you will need "something" which selects the right connection string per configuration. There are many ways of doing this, but it's hard to propose anything because I don't know what you consider "good" or what wouldn't make your fellow developers disgusted. I think you should explain better your requirements.

Comment: I have Debug and Release transforms, so three configurations in total.  The Debug constant wouldn't be a good choice to use because it's used by diagnostics tools.  You may well want to turn it on for some arbitrary build.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the dotnet CLI, then you can specify the target build configuration via the

`--configuration`

argument, which will result in the correct connection string being selected by the tool.